# Passing a variable between non-nested components using Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Suppose I have two components which aren't nested: a button and a panel. When the button is clicked, the panel will show or hide depending on the previous state (like an on/off switch). They aren't nested components, so the structure looks like this:

```
<div>
    <Toolbar>
        <Button />
    </Toolbar>
    <Content>
        ...
        <ButtonPanel />
    </Content>
</div>
```

I can't change the structure of the DOM. I also can't modify any other component other than the button and panel components.

The `Button` and `ButtonPanel` components are related, however, and will be used together throughout the solution. I need to pass a property to the panel to let it know when to show or when to hide. I was thinking about doing it with Context API, but I think there's something I'm doing wrong and the property never updates.

This is my code:

**Context**

```
import React from 'react';

export const ButtonContext = React.createContext({
  showPanel: false,
});
```

**Button**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ButtonContext } from './ButtonContext';

class Button extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showPanel: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonContext.Provider value={{ showPanel: this.state.showPanel }}>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={() => this.setState({ showPanel: !this.state.showPanel }, () => console.log('Changed'))}
          >
            <span>Button</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ButtonContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { Button };
```

**Panel**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Panel, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ButtonContext } from './ButtonContext';

class ButtonPanel extends Component {
  static contextType = ButtonContext;
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonContext.Consumer>
        {
          ({ showPanel }) => {
            if (showPanel) {
              return (
                <Panel id="tasksPanel">
                  <Panel.Heading >Panel Heading</Panel.Heading>
                  <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem>No Items.</ListGroupItem>
                  </ListGroup>
                </Panel>
              );
            }
            return null;
          }
        }
      </ButtonContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export { ButtonPanel };
```

I've also tried simply accessing the context in the `ButtonPanel` component like so:

```
render() {
    const context = this.context;
    return context.showPanel ?
      (
        <Panel id="tasksPanel">
          <Panel.Heading >Tasks</Panel.Heading>
          <ListGroup>
            <ListGroupItem className="tasks-empty-state">No tasks available.</ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
        </Panel>
      )
      :
      null;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does it log `Changed`? And doesnt `ButtonContext.Provider` have to wrap `ButtonContext.Consumer`?

Comment: It logs _"Changed"_ alright. I don't know what you mean about the provider having to wrap the consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider):

> Accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming components that are **descendants** of this Provider.

So this means that `<ButtonContext.Provider>` has to wrap `<ButtonContext.Consumer>` or it has to be higher up in the component hierarchy.

So based on your use case, you could do:

```
// This app component is the div that wraps both Toolbar and Content. You can name it as you want
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showPanel: false,
  }

  handleTogglePanel = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ togglePanel: !prevState.togglePanel }));

 render() {
   return (
     <ButtonContext.Provider value={{ showPanel: this.state.showPanel, handleTogglePanel: this.handleTogglePanel }}>
       <Toolbar>
         <Button />
       </Toolbar>
       <Content>
         <ButtonPanel />
       </Content>
     </ButtonContext.Provider>
   );
 }
}

class Button extends Component {
  ...
    <ButtonContext.Consumer>
      {({ handleTogglePanel }) => <a onClick={handleTogglePanel} />}
    </ButtonContext.Consumer>
}

class ButtonPanel extends Component {
  ...
    <ButtonContext.Consumer>
      {({ showPanel }) => showPanel && <Panel>...</Panel>}
    </ButtonContext.Consumer>
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. I can't change anything in the container App in which the `Button` and `ButtonPanel` components are nested. Is there another way to link them?

Comment: @Heathcliff may i know the reason why? If u really cant u can look into redux